Upgrading from MPLAB ICD-2 to ICD-3 to move from PIC 18F87J10 to PIC 18F87K22
For my hobby I used to get boards for a particular device, and used to reprogram the microchip PIC 18F87J10 using MPLAB ICD-2 (I run it from my VM VirtualBox running Windows XP). Now the company from which I get the boards has replaced the microchip with PIC 18F87K22, which is not supported by ICD-2 but is by ICD-3. So I bought a used ICD-3 on eBay.
In the past I was running MPLAB v7.60, which was ICD-2 capable. But a friend found a zip from Microchip to install MPLAB v8.92. Now ICD-3 shows in the menu, but if I try to use it, a window pops up stating that it must download new firmware to work. A search on the Microchip website for ICD-3 firmware update, doesn't show anything newer.
Can anybody please point me in the right direction to complete the connection with the new ICD-3 device?
--- EDIT ---
As suggested in the comment by @jasonharper, after clicking OK for the firmware download, the following dialog appears
MPLAB ICD 3 detected
Connecting to MPLAB ICD 3...
Firmware Suite Version...... 01.26.81
Firmware type......................PIC32MX
Downloading AP...
AP download complete

But it seems hung up on connecting, and the green-dot bar showing that the connection is ongoing never stops cycling, as illustrated by the screenshot.


You shouldn't need to download anything - MPLAB should contain the firmware for all supported development tools already, it's just letting you know that it will have to install that firmware before it can use the tool.

MPLAB is pretty old. You should update to MPLABX!

It seems that eventually everything worked as @jasonharper commented.

You shouldn't need to download anything - MPLAB should contain the firmware for all supported development tools already. It's just letting you know that it will have to install that firmware before it can use the tool.

